# Should a subclass of SimpleChannelInboundHandler call super methods in overrides?

Tags: netty

I'm subclassing `SimpleChannelInboundHandler` and overriding `channelRead0()`  as well as few other methods such as`channelActive()` and `exceptionCaught()`.

In these overrides, should I be calling their super class counterparts somewhere?

e.g.

```
public class FooHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<HttpObject> {

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        // do something here

        // do I need this?
        super.channelActive(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        // do something here

        // or this?
        super.channelInactive(ctx);
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need it if you want to have the next handler in the pipeline also receive the events, otherwise not. So it really depends on what you want to do.